# Silverlight 4 with wcf service - cross domain policy issue

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I get the below warning message when i compile my project in the Visual Studio.

Warning 1 Could not locate cross-domain policy at 'MyServer': Web services might not be 
accessible at runtime by your Silverlight application.

When i run my application also it fails . I have added the cross

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it at the root of the web server for instance: http://mybiz.com/clientaccesspolicy.xml